# PHP Load Image if exist?

Tags: php, if-statement, exists

I am using this code for a slideshow:

```
<img src="<?php echo($array[0]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[1]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[2]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[3]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[4]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[5]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[6]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[7]); ?>"/>
```

I want to show images, only if they exist.
Sometimes the $array has only 5 values.

How is this posible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should loop over the array values and echo an image tag for each value:

```
<?php
foreach($array as $img){
    echo '<img src="'.$img.'"/>'."\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

That's the perfect opportunity for a loop. You can either use a [`for`](http://php.net/for) loop (since your array is numerically indexed) or a [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) loop.

---

**Using a [`for`](http://php.net/for) loop:**

```
<?php $count = count($array); for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++): ?>
  <img src="<?php echo($array[$i]); ?>" />
<?php endfor; ?>
```

In traditional syntax:

```
<?php $count = count($array); for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) { ?>
  <img src="<?php echo($array[$i]); ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

---

**Using a [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) loop:**

```
<?php foreach($array as $img): ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In traditional syntax:

```
<?php foreach($array as $img) { ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

---

Since this is a fairly basic question, I suggest you take the time to read the PHP Documentation chapter about **control structures**. There are essential. It is available here:

> [PHP Documentation: Control Structures](http://php.net/control-structures)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $src){ echo "<img src='$src' />"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
{
?>
  <img src="<?php echo($array[$i]); ?>"/>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach($array as $img){
    if(file_exists($img))
    echo '<img src="'.$img.'"/>'."\n";
}
?>
```